# WinGet multiple ahk_pid Process IDs within single AHK file

Tags: autohotkey

I'm creating an ahk script where I am trying to single to use the same logic across multiple Process IDs.

I have more than 5 of this window class / process name running, so I'm using the ahk_pid to specify the 2 that I want the script to run for.

I could open 2 separate files and specify a single ahk_pid in each, but is there a way to specify 2+ ahk_pids within a single script file?

When I try something similar to below, the script works for only the top pid.

```
pid = 1234
pid2 = 4321
WinGetTitle, clickTitle, ahk_pid %pid%
WinGetTitle, clickTitle, ahk_pid %pid2%
WinGetClass, clickClass, ahk_pid %pid%
WinGetClass, clickClass, ahk_pid %pid2%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same variable names for each `WinGetTitle` and `WinGetClass`. I tried using your code with two Notepad instances (and unique variables) and it ran successfully. With unique variable names, you can use your method with as many ahk_PID as you wish in one script.

```
f1::
pid = 1234
pid2 = 4321
WinGetTitle, clickTitle, ahk_pid %pid%
WinGetTitle, clickTitle2, ahk_pid %pid2%
WinGetClass, clickClass, ahk_pid %pid%
WinGetClass, clickClass2, ahk_pid %pid2%
ListVars
Return
```